# infinispan(embedded with spring 4) is not caching for wildfly 9.0.0 .

Tags: spring, infinispan, wildfly-9

Infinispan(embedded with spring 4) is not caching for wildfly 9.0.0 . can anybody help me with correct configurations and compatible versions?

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please post you configuration and describe what you are trying to do?

In the meantime, please have a look at [Spring - Infinispan tutorial](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-simple-tutorials/tree/master/spring) and [documentation](http://infinispan.org/docs/8.2.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_using_infinispan_as_a_spring_cache_provider).